# Maps and Cloud Google API Acces

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently, we use Google Maps service on our brand websites to allow consumers to locate the nearest sales point to their address through the Maps API integrated into our website.

Today, we lost access to the API, and the Maps stopped functioning on the site. It's crucial for us to regain access as we are investing in media for the page, and consumers are unable to use the service.

We've tried various emails and passwords, but none grant us access, and we need to resolve this issue as soon as possible. Can you help us?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has nothing to do with programming. Nobody here can help recovering accounts, ask directly to google.